# How to remove cursor that show on selectmenus?

Tags: jquery, ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have cursor that show above `Selectmenu` when clicking many times above this `Selectmenu`?

[image]

And this some code

```
<center>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%;">
                    <label for="Column1" class="select PSettinglabel">
                        Column 1</label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 70%;">
                    <div class="dropdowncssclass" >
                        <select name="Column1" id="Column1" data-native-menu="true">
                            <option value="SymbolName">Symbole Name</option>
                            <option value="SymbolID">Symbole ID</option>
                            <option value="Symbol">Symbole ID & Name</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 <center>
```

This is PhoneGap Application under iOS.
Please, any one faced this issue and found solution tell me about the solution?
Also, Any suggestion would be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a cursor. jQuery Mobile style nor select box don't have a inner element capable of showing a blinking cursor.

I think you have a problem with your implementation of select box styling and that "cursor" is just a span selection.

If I am correct this css should help you:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```